# How to Implement dark mode in React native Classes React navigation 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, darkmode

Im trying to implement dark mode to my app. How to do that in classes in React navigation V5

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68005237/11711280 answers this for reactjs

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);//seems to be the same here for reactjs as react-native
    this.darkModeQuery = window.matchMedia(`(prefers-color-scheme: dark)`);
    this.lightModeQuery = window.matchMedia(`(prefers-color-scheme: light)`);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.darkModeListener = navigation.addListener(this.darkModeQuery, this.setDark);
    this.lightModeListener = navigation.addListener(this.lightModeQuery, this.setLight);
  }
  setDark = (darkModeQuery) =>
    this.setState({
      darkMode: darkModeQuery.length !== 0,
      darkModeListener: darkModeQuery
    });
  setLight = (lightModeQuery) =>
    this.setState({
      lightMode: lightModeQuery.length !== 0,
      lightModeListener: lightModeQuery
    });
  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { lightModeListener, darkModeListener } = this.state;
    if (lightModeListener)
      this.lightModeListener.remove();
    if (darkModeListener)
      this.darkModeListener.remove();
  }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590338/11711280 I found asking how to translate `window.addEventListener(this.mediaQuery,this.myFunc)` for `this.darkModeListener = navigator.addEventListener(this.mediaQuery,this.myFunc)`